# Blacklist React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to define a function to hook before **each** component in my app is mounted?

The idea is that if a component is *blacklisted* it doesn't mount at all.

The solution must leave the components unmodified for backward compatibility and should run in production (so rewire and other testing tools are probably off the table but open to suggestions :) )

#### Example

```
//something like this...
ReactDOM.beforeEachComponentMount( (component, action) => {
    if(isBlacklisted(component)){
        action.cancelMountComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that does not exist, but you can try wrapping all of your components in a HOC component, and that will only have one `componentDidMount`, where you can do your blacklisted checks.

Comment: Thanks for your response @DragoşPaulMarinescu but I'd really like to leave the hundreds of components distributed in multiple codebases alone and allow engineers to use all the React functionality as this blacklist didn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such functionality out of box.

You may shim React rendering cycle, I mean shim `React.createElement` method and validate component before it is added to VDOM

All JSX is processed through `React.createElement`

e.g. at the start of app add

```
let React = require('react');
let originalCreateElement = React.createElement;
React.createElement = function() {
    let componentConstructorOrStringTagName = arguments[0];
    if (isBlacklisted(componentConstructorOrStringTagName)) {
        return null;
    }
    return originalCreateElement.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Could you write a simple Babel plugin that transforms blacklisted components to a noop functional component `() => {}` at compile time?

Comment: Looks like the only viable solution so far, care to elaborate a bit more? Would that compromise debug in development mode?

Comment: I think how to write a Babel plugin is probably out of the scope of this question, but I think simply transforming a component to `() => {}` based on a blacklist of component names should be pretty easy.

How do you mean "compromise debug"? From the point of view of debug tools the component would be `() => {}`, the original implementation having already been totally transformed out of the app by Babel before it gets rendered anywhere.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I need to be able to change the blacklisted components at run-time and this seems to be a more compile time thing. Correct me if wrong please @WildService

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap the required components inside a higher order component that checks whether the component is blacklisted or not.

for example :

```
class YourComponent extends Component {   
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
 }

 render(){
  return(
    // your component goes here .. 
  );
  }
}
export default WithPermission(YourComponent);
```

check if the component needs to be rendered or not inside the HOC *WithPermission*.

```
function withPermission(YourComponent) {
  class WithPermission extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }

// you can check the props inside ComponentDidMount and set a flag if 
// the component satisfies the criteria for rendering.

 render() {
  const {blacklistedComponents,...rest} = this.props;
   if(!blackListedComponents){
    return <YourComponent {...rest} />
   }
   else{
    return null;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It's a good way to solve the problem unless you have hundreds of existing components, and you want to avoid cognitive overhead for engineers in my team who would probably just want to use standard react semantic.

Answer (score 2):

The best idea I can think of is to "shim" `react` and `Component`

if you are using webpack you can use this:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

in the bottom line that means instead of importing `react` you will import your own class of react.

In your new class you could extend React Component and place a check on the `render` function or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom ESLint rule and catch this as soon as a dev tries to use a blacklisted components. The [id-blacklist](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/id-blacklist) rule is similar to what you want, but at the identifier level. The [source code](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/rules/id-blacklist.js) looks simple. Maybe you can adapt it to disallow more then just identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following solution:

Let there be a file where you declare which components are blacklisted:

```
let blacklist = [{
   name: 'secretComponent',
   invoke: (props)=> {
       return <SecretComponent ...props />
   },
   isBlacklisted: true
},{
   name: 'home',
   invoke: (props)=> {
       return <HomeComponent ...props />
   },
   isBlacklisted: false
},{
   name: 'login',
   invoke: (props)=> {
       return <LoginComponent ...props />
   },
   isBlacklisted: false
}];
```

Define a Higher Order Component like below:

```
function renderIfNotBlacklisted(name) {
    let component = blacklist.map(x=> x.name == name); //blacklist from above
    if (!component.isBlacklisted){
        return component.invoke();
    } //else can be handled as you will
    //You can keep a default component to render or send empty values
}
```

Call this component in the render function wherever you want this feature to work. This way you have a centralized location to managed blacklisted components (blacklist.json can be in the root of react project or fetched from API on first run)

Comment: Thanks Shiro, but this would go against my principle of not changing components that already exist. The idea is to leave the hundreds of existing components residing in multiple codebases and libraries, untaouched and still provide a centralised control over their rendering.

Comment: Welcome snovelli. Please tell me something. Are these components which are to be blacklisted rendered as main component for a particular route or are they nested inside a parent component?
Is there any other unique way to identity each component? Maybe id or something?